# which ids contain the two highest values per column

Tags: r

I wonder how I get which ids contain the two highest values per column.

```
id <- c("A", "B", "C", "D","E")
a <- c(1,3,4,5,NA)
b <- c(1,NA,NA,5,9)
c <- c(NA,3,4,5,3)

d <- data.frame(id,a,b,c)
d
```

Wanted output

```
    column a
    id=C, D
    column b
    id = D, E
    column c
    id=D, E
```

Answer (score 1):

In base R using `sapply` :

```
sapply(d[-1], function(x) toString(head(d$id[order(-x)], 2)))

#     a      b      c 
#"D, C" "E, D" "D, C"
```

This can be written in `dplyr` as :

```
library(dplyr)
d %>% summarise(across(a:c, ~toString(head(id[order(-.)], 2))))
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `dapply` from `collapse` which would be faster

```
library(collapse)
dapply(d[-1], function(x) paste(d$id[order(-x)][1:2], collapse=", "))
#     a      b      c 
#"D, C" "E, D" "D, C"
```